# Color Specific Rows using Longtable - Latex

Tags: tables, longtable

Before ask for help I search here but, with no luck.

I have a long table latex (I'm using longtable environment). I want to color some specific rows in gray (lines: 2, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 21, 29 and 32). Can you guys help me to achieve this? Thank you in advance.
Here's my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,booktabs,siunitx,caption}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \small
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}           
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} 
        \begin{longtable}{ccccc}
        \caption{Tabela Nome dos Candidatos. Elaborado por Autor. 2020.} \label{tab:tabelaNomeCandidatosColigacao} \\
        
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\makecell{Número \\ do Candidato}}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\makecell{Nome do Candidato \\ (urna)}}}  &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Partido}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\makecell{Votos Nominais \\ do Candidato}}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\makecell{\% Votos \\ Válidos}}}  \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Número do Candidato}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\makecell{Nome do Candidato \\ (urna)}}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Partido}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\makecell{Votos Nominais \\ do Candidato}}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\makecell{\% Votos \\ Válidos}}} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        
        \midrule
        \endfoot
        
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        44444 & JORGE KAJURU  & PRP & 37.796 & 5,65 \\ 
        \rowcolor{gray!40}
        45233 & DRA. CRISTINA  & PSDB & 9.114 & 1,36 \\
        \makecell{90100} & \makecell{VINICIUS CIRQUEIRA}  & \makecell{PROS} & 8.582 & 1,28 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        10123 & ROGERIO CRUZ  & PRB & 8.312 & 1,24 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        45602 & ANSELMO PEREIRA  & PSDB & 7.504 & 1,12 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        40001 & ELIAS VAZ  & PSB & 7.487 & 1,12 \\
        23456 & CARLIN CAFÉ  & PPS & 7.392 & 1,1 \\
        \makecell{10010} & \makecell{ALYSSON LIMA}  & \makecell{PRB} & 7.257 & 1,08 \\
        \makecell{35789} & \makecell{SABRINA GARCEZ}  & \makecell{PMB} & 7.233 & 1,08 \\
        \makecell{22222} & \makecell{FELISBERTO TAVARES}  & \makecell{PR} & 6.670 & 1 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        15700 & WELINGTON PEIXOTO  & PMDB & 6.513 & 0,97 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        12345 & PAULINHO GRAUS  & PDT & 6.452 & 0,96 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        40321 & OSÉIAS VARÃO  & PSB & 6.171 & 0,92 \\
        \makecell{22123} & \makecell{IZIDIO ALVES}  & \makecell{PR} & 5.889 & 0,88 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        27500 & KLEYBE MORAIS  & PSDC & 5.818 & 0,87 \\
        \makecell{15015} & \makecell{CLECIO ALVES}  & \makecell{PRP} & 5.415 & 5,65 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        90900 & TIAOZINHO PORTO  & PROS & 4.878 & 0,73 \\
        \makecell{55555} & \makecell{PRISCILLA TEJOTA}  & \makecell{PSD} & 4.807 & 0,72 \\
        \makecell{17000} & \makecell{LUCAS KITÃO}  & \makecell{PSL} & 4.499 & 0,67 \\
        \makecell{55015} & \makecell{PAULO MAGALHÃES}  & \makecell{PSD} & 4.482 & 0,67 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        65123 & TATIANA LEMOS  & PC do B & 4.418 & 0,66 \\
        \makecell{43444} & \makecell{DELEGADO EDUARDO PRADO}  & \makecell{PV} & 4.237 & 0,63 \\
        \makecell{15678} & \makecell{ANDREY AZEREDO}  & \makecell{PMDB} & 4.073 & 0,61 \\
        \makecell{43400} & \makecell{GUSTAVO CRUVINEL}  & \makecell{PV} & 4.066 & 0,61 \\
        \makecell{27900} & \makecell{JAIR DIAMANTINO}  & \makecell{PSDC} & 3.889 & 0,58 \\
        \makecell{28123} & \makecell{JUAREZ LOPES}  & \makecell{PRTB} & 3.753 & 0,56 \\
        \makecell{27100} & \makecell{ANDERSON SALES BOKÃO}  & \makecell{PSDC} & 3.479 & 0,52 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        51800 & ZANDER  & PEN & 3.501 & 0,52 \\
        20500 & LEIA KLEBIA  & PSC & 3.367 & 0,5 \\
        \makecell{36153} & \makecell{GCM ROMÁRIO POLICARPO}  & \makecell{PTC} & 3.185 & 0,48 \\
        \makecell{44321} & \makecell{MILTON MERCEZ}  & \makecell{PRP} & 2.886 & 0,43 \\
        \makecell{44190} & \makecell{CABO SENNA}  & \makecell{PRP} & 2.795 & 0,42 \\
        19123 & SARGENTO NOVANDIR  & PTN & 2.713 & 0,41 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!40!}
        25555 & DR. PAULO DAHER  & DEM & 2.511 & 0,38 \\
        \makecell{19123} & \makecell{EMILSON PEREIRA}  & \makecell{PTN} & 2.429 & 0,36 \\
        
        \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason for all the `\makecell` commands?

Comment: Without the `\makecell` commands, the `\rowcolor` command works perfectly fine: `\rowcolor{gray!80!}
        45233 & DRA. CRISTINA  & PSDB & 9.114 & 1,36 \\ `

Comment: I will remove them. Not using it for anything on this table. Just want to color those specific rows with gray and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Why did you decide to use a `\tabcolsep` of just 1pt? As you can see from the table headers of the two last columns, with such a small tabcolsep, the text in the two columns will almost touch.

Comment: No way @leandriis, I just tested here and worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @leandriis I used 1pt to fit the \longtable on page. Do you know how to fit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109590/discussion-between-guilherme-schults-and-leandriis).

Comment: unrelated but don't put `longtable` in a center enviornment it just produces vertical space and doesn't have any effect on its alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this indeed happened here. I'm having problem to fit the longtable on the page. Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Without knowing the textwidth and font size, it is hard to tell you how you can ensure your table fits into the textwidth.

Comment: you have not provided a usable test file and in particular given no indication of how wide your page is so it's not really possible to say much, please fix your example so people can run it to see the problem.

Comment: you should also delete `\setlength\LTleft{0pt}     \setlength\LTright{0pt}` as that will just make every row of the table underfull in the normal case that it would otherwise fit.

Comment: @leandriis I just updated my post to work with a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might serve as a point to start from. Since there was no documentclass of other information about the size of the margins given in the original code, I guessed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} 
  \begin{longtable}{cllcc}
  \caption{Tabela Nome dos Candidatos. Elaborado por Autor. 2020.}
  \label{tab:tabelaNomeCandidatosColigacao} \\
  
  \toprule
  \thead{Número \\ do\\ Candidato} & 
  \thead{Nome do Candidato \\ (urna)}  &
  \thead{Partido} &
  \thead{Votos\\ Nominais  do\\ Candidato} &
  \thead{\% Votos \\ Válidos}  \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  
  \toprule
  \thead{Número \\ do\\ Candidato} & 
  \thead{Nome do Candidato \\ (urna)}  &
  \thead{Partido} &
  \thead{Votos\\ Nominais  do\\ Candidato} &
  \thead{\% Votos \\ Válidos}  \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  
  \midrule
  \endfoot
  
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  
                       44444 & JORGE KAJURU            & PRP & 37.796 & 5,65 \\ 
  \rowcolor{lightgray} 45233 & DRA. CRISTINA           & PSDB    & 9.114 & 1,36 \\
                       90100 & VINICIUS CIRQUEIRA      & PROS    & 8.582 & 1,28 \\
  \rowcolor{lightgray} 10123 & ROGERIO CRUZ            & PRB     & 8.312 & 1,24 \\
  \rowcolor{lightgray} 45602 & ANSELMO PEREIRA         & PSDB    & 7.504 & 1,12 \\
  \rowcolor{lightgray} 40001 & ELIAS VAZ               & PSB     & 7.487 & 1,12 \\
                       23456 & CARLIN CAFÉ             & PPS     & 7.392 & 1,1  \\
                       10010 & ALYSSON LIMA            & PRB     & 7.257 & 1,08 \\
                       35789 & SABRINA GARCEZ          & PMB     & 7.233 & 1,08 \\
                       22222 & FELISBERTO TAVARES      & PR      & 6.670 & 1    \\
                       15700 & WELINGTON PEIXOTO       & PMDB    & 6.513 & 0,97 \\
                       12345 & PAULINHO GRAUS          & PDT     & 6.452 & 0,96 \\
                       40321 & OSÉIAS VARÃO            & PSB     & 6.171 & 0,92 \\
                       22123 & IZIDIO ALVES            & PR      & 5.889 & 0,88 \\
                       27500 & KLEYBE MORAIS           & PSDC    & 5.818 & 0,87 \\
                       15015 & CLECIO ALVES            & PRP     & 5.415 & 5,65 \\
                       90900 & TIAOZINHO PORTO         & PROS    & 4.878 & 0,73 \\
                       55555 & PRISCILLA TEJOTA        & PSD     & 4.807 & 0,72 \\
                       17000 & LUCAS KITÃO             & PSL     & 4.499 & 0,67 \\
                       55015 & PAULO MAGALHÃES         & PSD     & 4.482 & 0,67 \\
                       65123 & TATIANA LEMOS           & PC do B & 4.418 & 0,66 \\
                       43444 & DELEGADO EDUARDO PRADO  & PV      & 4.237 & 0,63 \\
                       15678 & ANDREY AZEREDO          & PMDB    & 4.073 & 0,61 \\
                       43400 & GUSTAVO CRUVINEL        & PV      & 4.066 & 0,61 \\
                       27900 & JAIR DIAMANTINO         & PSDC    & 3.889 & 0,58 \\
                       28123 & JUAREZ LOPES            & PRTB    & 3.753 & 0,56 \\
                       27100 & ANDERSON SALES BOKÃO    & PSDC    & 3.479 & 0,52 \\
                       51800 & ZANDER                  & PEN     & 3.501 & 0,52 \\
                       20500 & LEIA KLEBIA             & PSC     & 3.367 & 0,5  \\
                       36153 & GCM ROMÁRIO POLICARPO   & PTC     & 3.185 & 0,48 \\
                       44321 & MILTON MERCEZ           & PRP     & 2.886 & 0,43 \\
                       44190 & CABO SENNA              & PRP     & 2.795 & 0,42 \\
                       19123 & SARGENTO NOVANDIR       & PTN     & 2.713 & 0,41 \\
                       25555 & DR. PAULO DAHER         & DEM     & 2.511 & 0,38 \\
                       19123 & EMILSON PEREIRA         & PTN     & 2.429 & 0,36 \\
  
  \end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help !!!!! It really did the trick for me. Also, now I know how to post any question with MWE.